# KeyboardAvoidingView overlapping header

Tags: javascript, react-native, header

I have a problem with KeyboardAvoidingView where my container seems to be overlapping my header when I clicked the text input like this
[image]
 and I'm using header from react native elements

here is my code

```js
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding" enabled>
                <Header
                        left={<IconWrapper
                            image={<Image source={img.icons.menu} style={{ width: normalize(26), resizeMode: 'contain', paddingHorizontal: normalize(5), marginHorizontal: normalize(5) }} />}
                            onPress={() => Actions.drawerOpen()} />}
                        title={'Activity Log'}
                        right={<View style={{ width: normalize(30) }} />}
                    />
                <View style={styles.innerContainer}> 
                  
                    <Text style={styles.dialogText}>{`Log my activity at ${time} as...`}</Text>
                    <View style={{marginVertical: 10}}>
                        {columns}
                    </View>                  
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder={"Additional Notes"}
                    />
                </View>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
            
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
    container: {
        flex:1,
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },

    innerContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
})
```

Comment: try to put your header outside the KeyboardAvoidingView

Comment: I can't it says 'JSX expressions must have one parent element.' @YashVaghela

Comment: make one parent <VIEW> then put your header and then KeyboardAvoidingView

Comment: it still overlapping the header, now I'm using keyboard-aware-scroll-view @YashVaghela